# Not able to compile/Build Lemon Graph library: Gives missing library

Tags: lemon-graph-library, coin-or-cbc

I am trying to build Lemon on my VM running ubuntu having gcc and g++ 4.9.2, but it keeps on giving the following error. I tried installing glpk, Soplex and ILOG Ciplex, but the error didn't go away. Following is the error.

Apparently, this issue is mentioned as fixed in lemon-1.3.1, but I am using the same and seems like it still persist.

Kindly let me know if anyone have an idea about how to solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with the 1.3.1 tarball on a Linux Ubuntu 14.04 machine - cmake failed, because I had no GLPK, ILOG, COIN and SOPLEX installed.

But the development version from the repository doesn't complain:

```
hg clone http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/hg/lemon
```

If you prefer a version release, 1.3.0 from the repo builds for me too (1.3.1 doesn't):

```
hg clone http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/hg/lemon
hg checkout 1.3
```

Comment: This 1.3.1 tarball was specifically needed for the project. What I did was that I installed SOPLEX and GLPK from their respective repositories and then went ahead, and somehow it worked. I also tried to remove the dependences of the other from the makefile. All of them are more or less linear programming solvers.  

It also works smooth on Ubuntu 15.04 machine.

Comment: The updated source can be download from this website: http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/hg/lemon/summary (also without having hg installed)

Answer (score 0):

Tested with the newest trunk:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```